# Problemas con webBrowser vb

Tags: vb.net

al ejecutar webBrowser1.Navigate("", True)  la pagina en la cual quiero ingresar tiene certificado. busque miles de formas para obtenerlos y que automáticamente entre a la pagina alguna solucion? gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando existen advertencias de certificados es porque la página que solicitas es https pero el certificado de seguridad no está emitido por una entidad reconocida (por ejemplo Symantec, DigiCert, Comodo) muy seguramente es una página autocertificada, es decir el propio servidor indica que la página es segura.

Cuando sucede esto, todos los navegadores (incluyendo el webbrowser de vb, el cual es un hermano pequeño de internet explorer) te dan una advertencia de la página y te preguntan si deseas continuar. Esto lo hace cada vez que entras a la página en cualquier máquina. Pero a menos que confíes en el servidor que lo emite; por ejemplo si es de una intranet empresarial, no deberías aceptar ya que podrías ser víctima de ataques de seguridad informática.

Por último, a menos que en la página se instale un certificado de una entidad reconocida, no hay manera de quitar los mensajes en todas las máquinas y efectivamente hay que realizar el mismo proceso de aceptar la página con un certificado no válido.